I'm trying to get SQLite with EXPO to work in a react-native project but code isn't modifying .db file
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';
  const insertCity = async () => {
const db = await SQLite.openDatabaseAsync('meteoDB.db');
await db.runAsync('INSERT INTO ville2 (name, type) VALUES (?, ?)', ['Paris', 1]);};


<Button onPress={insertCity} title="Test Database" />

image of Console output
    "expo-sqlite": "^15.0.3",
    "expo": "~52.0.18",

this is my code SQLite synatxe has changed alot and none of the Ai could help
new expo sqlite docs [here]
so this is basically what i'm trying to do(code above) but this dosen't actually change the content of the "meteoDB.db" file isntead i think it's storing this on a local db or memory (i'm not because i'm new to react-native and sqlLite both)
when i excute these commands i get what you see in image which is basically it saying that the table dosen't exist (on the local or idk where db) but in reality that table exist in the file because i created it manullay using sql in sqlBrowser(windows).
MY question is: do we have two kind of db here ? or is it just my code that's storing in a memory one instead of my file directly?
question 2: where should this file be ? in assests or just directly in root foolder?
thank you.
